# Determine if more than one MySQL server installed

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

Is there a way to find out if more than 1 MySQL server installed on a server?

Situation: I'm running an Ubuntu 14.04 with MySQL server installed by plesk, however the service is not starting automatically. I'm assuming that I have another MySQL server which starts instead of the correct one.

Any guide will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below command if any mysql service is running on your server-

```
ps -aux | grep mysql
```

It will show you how many mysql services are running on server or not.

Comment: I see 2 records returned. Is there anyway to uninstall one without affecting the other one?

Comment: mysql      905  0.0  8.8 878760 90172 ?        Ssl  16:14   0:01 /usr/sbin/mysqld
servera+  2803  0.0  0.2  11752  2080 pts/0    S+   16:40   0:00 grep --color=au to mysql

Comment: normally this command show you 3 process...1 for grep mysql your latest command...and other 2 for mysql service 1 for .sock file and 1 for .pid file. but both these will show same data directory....if you are getting any mysql process with different datadir then you can kill that process by "kill 123" command where 123 is here your process id.